# matplotlib pcolormesh behaviour with large arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot an array, but run into a problem when the array gets too large. However, it seems to depend on whether or not the data is monotonic. In the example below, I increase the size of the array that I am plotting. The expected behaviour is the same image in the left and right hand sides, but this is not so. Furthermore, the size of the array I am able to plot correctly seems to depend on the size of the axis itself. When the figures are exported, there is no problem - just the display on the screen, which looks like the screenshot below:

[image]

````
len_xs = [4850,4860,4870] # sizes to try and plot
for j in np.arange(3):
    x = np.arange(len_xs[j]); # dummy x variable
    y = 2**np.linspace(-4.18676100,1.39659793,538) # log2 spaced y variable
    z = np.random.random((len(y),len(x))) # random variable to plot
    
    plt.subplot(3,2,j*2+1); 
    if j==0: plt.title('Right way up')
    plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z,shading='Nearest');
    plt.gca().set_yscale('log',base=2)```

    plt.subplot(3,2,j*2+2); 
    if j==0: plt.title('Upside down')

    plt.pcolormesh(x,y[::-1],z[::-1],shading='Nearest'); # flip y and z
    plt.gca().set_yscale('log',base=2); 
    plt.text(1000,1,'nx = %g'%len_xs[j],bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8)) # annotate size of x
    
plt.savefig('demo.png',dpi=600)
````

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - the image looks fine on my machine using the pyQt5 backend.  You should specify what you mean the "the display on the screen".

Comment: Clarified. The image in the OP is from the on-screen display, not the .png file.

Comment: Yes but how are you displaying it on the screen?  Which backend are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is unknown, but since the DPI of the saved image is high, it was displayed with the same content as the saved file, which matched the DPI of the display accordingly.

```
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 600
```

[image]